# wordpress ninja forms submit button stuck on processing

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

When a user clicks the submit button the form is posted and the information is saved in the database. However, the button text hangs on Processing and the user never get confirmation.
The console error returns the following

```
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4 POST https://www.x.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
front-end.js?ver=3.4.31:4951 ERRORS: Internal Server Error
front-end.js?ver=3.4.31:4952
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort: ƒ (a)
always: ƒ ()
complete: ƒ ()
done: ƒ ()
error: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
getResponseHeader: ƒ (a)
overrideMimeType: ƒ (a)
pipe: ƒ ()
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ (a)
readyState: 4
responseText: "There has been a critical error on your website"
setRequestHeader: ƒ (a,b)
state: ƒ ()
status: 500
statusCode: ƒ (a)
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
success: ƒ ()
then: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
front-end.js?ver=3.4.31:4959 Parse Error
front-end.js?ver=3.4.31:2275 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nonce' of undefined
at i.submitErrors (front-end.js?ver=3.4.31:2275)
at p (backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:2)
at f (backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:2)
at l (backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:2)
at u.Channel.n.trigger (backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:2)
at Object.error (front-end.js?ver=3.4.31:4963)
at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
at x (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4)
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4 XHR failed loading: POST "https://www.x.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php".
send @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4
ajax @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4
submit @ front-end.js?ver=3.4.31:4931
u._callHandler @ front-end-deps.js?ver=3.4.31:23
request @ front-end-deps.js?ver=3.4.31:23
click @ front-end.js?ver=3.4.31:2023
p @ backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:2
f @ backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:2
l @ backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:2
n.trigger @ backbone.min.js?ver=1.4.0:2
fieldClick @ front-end.js?ver=3.4.31:4472
dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3
r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, wordpress was being hosted in an aws environment and the form had an email trigger. Ninja forms was able to save the information but when it handed off the email duties to the smtp plugin it failed by timing out. The solution was to add the smtp connecting port to the aws outbound firewall.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using a hook, disable that go to functions.php remove line like this

```
add_action('ninja_forms_after_submission', 'custom_ninja_forms_after_submission', 10, 1);
```

> I hope this will fix your issue.